# How to create a trigger that deletes rows from tables when a row is deleted in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have user_id in users table as a primary key and this is used as a foreign key in other tables. I want to create a trigger so that whenever a row is deleted from users the corresponding rows with the same user_id in other tables are also deleted.

My code is as follows;

```
create trigger deletereview
after delete on users
for each row
    delete from recommendation
    where users.user_id = recommendation.creator_id and users.user_id = recommendation.reciever_id;
create trigger deletereview_2
after delete on users
for each row
    delete from user_attractions 
    where users.user_id = user_attractions.user_id;
create trigger deletereview_3
after delete on users
for each row
    delete from user_property
    where users.user_id = user_property.user_id
```

Whenever I try to run this and delete a row from users I get 'Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails'.

After setting foreign key checks to 0 with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

I get this error 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause''

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Would be easier to use [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: The delete fails because of the FK, so the trigger isn't executed. Disabling FK's to prevent this is overkill, better use a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger (if `ON DELETE CASCADE` isn't an option)